# AS: Hand over points to GameOverActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, points

I´ve got one GameActivity and one GameOverActivity. I saved the points of my game in my GameActivity, but will show up these in my GameOverActivity. What I have to do?
My gameActivity:

```
 public void finishGameActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("points", points);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
 }

 public void setPoints(){
    points++;
    TextView points_show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
    points_show.setText("Points: " + points);
}


public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int points;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
    changeFont();
    TextView points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point_stats);
}

private void changeFont(){
    TextView gameover = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameover);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  
"fonts/font.ttf");
    gameover.setTypeface(custom_font);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sharedPreferences to save your current score globally. Else if you just want to pass the score with an intent, use .GetExtras() in the target intent

Comment: Read the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java  I would use sharedprefs to save your score

Comment: getActivity() doesn´t exists.

Comment: Use the 'this' keyword to get context of activity you are currently in. You can also type gameactivity.this from another activity. You should be able to use getactovity(), what is the error?